# Actualizar variable de sesión mostrada desde php sin necesidad de recargar la pagina Web

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session

Muy buenas, me encuentro desarrollando un sistema web de carrito de compras en MySQL, PHP y Javascript, en todas las paginas se halla un include que muestra mis variables de 'totalcoste' y 'cantidadtotal' en un menú top aqui el código:

```
<div class="cell-7 right-bar" >
    <ul class="right">

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION["cantidadTotal"])) {?>
            <li ><a href="carrito.php"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><?php echo $_SESSION["cantidadTotal"]; ?> item(s) - S/.<?php echo $_SESSION["totalcoste"]; ?></a></li>
    <?php } else {?>
            <li ><a href="carrito.php"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>0 item(s) - S/.0.00</a></li>
    <?php } ?>

        <li><a href="registro.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="login-btn"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

La cuestión es que necesito que estos datos sesión mostrados se actualicen de acuerdo a los cambios que haga, digamos que en la pagina de *productodetalle* de click al botón "agregar al carrito", estos datos mostrados se actualicen al modificar los datos sesión aunque sea la variable de 'cantidadtotal' de productos en sesión.
Acá el código de agregar producto:

```
<div class="left">
    <input onclick="add2(<?php echo $pro['idtb_producto'];?>,'new',$('#items-num').val());" type="submit" 
        value="Agregar al Carrito"
        class="btn btn-medium add-cart main-bg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La `$_SESSION` se mantiene a lo largo del servidor de una forma increíble, aunque accedas de forma indirecta a un archivo `php` este igualmente puede diferenciar entre tu session u otra.
Por lo tanto en una petición `AJAX` también, puedes proceder de la siguiente forma:

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
// variable con lo que quieres sumarle a tu valor.
var sumarCant = 25;
$.ajax({
    data: {"parametro":sumarCant},
    type: "POST",
    url: "cambiarCantidadTotal.php",
    // Si el cambio se realiza correctamente: 
    success: function (nuevaCantidad) { 

        // "nuevaCantidad" contiene el nuevo valor de cantidadTotal
        console.log(nuevaCantidad);
    }
});
```

En el **PHP** lo preparas para recibir, actualizar el valor y devolver el nuevo.
Creas un fichero `cambiarCantidadTotal.php`:

```
<?php
    // Obtienes la cantidad a sumar
    $sumCant = $_POST["parametro"];

    // Abres la session y le sumas el valor
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["cantidadTotal"] += $sumCant;

    // Devuelves el nuevo valor para actualizar la pagina
    echo $_SESSION["cantidadTotal"];

?>
```

En el parámetro `success` puedes indicar la acción a realizar si el cambio ha sido completado y se te ha devuelto el valor.

Si le añades una `id="cantidadTotal"` podrias actualizar al momento el valor en `success`:

```
$("#valorTotal").html(nuevaCantidad);
```

Answer (score 0):

en la funcion add puedes enviar la información a otro PHP mediante ajax y en el **`<li>`** donde pones el precio le pondría un id para imprimir el valor guardado 
si usas jquery seria algo así

**html**

```
<li ><a href="carrito.php"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><div id="liCarrito"></div></li>
```

**JS**

```
//funcion del boton
add2(sku,str,val){
  //...
    $.post('guardarEnSesion.php',{val:val}).done(function(d){
      $("#liCarrito").html(d)
    })
  //...
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$_SESSION["cantidadTotal"] += $_POST["val"];
echo $_SESSION["cantidadTotal"];
```